# Data transmission using RF with raspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, telecommunication, rfcomm

I have a project that consisted of transmitting data wirelessly from 15 tractors to a station, the maximum distance between tractor and station is 13 miles. I used a raspberry pi 3 to collect data from tractors. with some research I found that there is no wifi or GSM coverage so the only solution is to use RF communication using VHF. so is that possible with raspberry pi or I must add a modem? if yes, what is the criterion for choosing a modem? and please if you have any other information tell me?
and thank you for your time.

Comment: Raspberry PI isn't going to communicate 13 miles out of the box. Have you considered logging to the Raspberry Pi and uploading at the end of the day (with WiFi) or does your data need to be transmitted close to real time?

Comment: Also worth noting that different countries have different rules about the spectrum you can and cannot transmit on, so you probably need to check the frequencies you can use also if you can't go the offline logging route as Nick suggests.

Comment: Good point. If you go the WiFi or GSM solution, the spectrums are all worked out for you, but you need some infrastructure (WiFi mesh or GSM towers)

Comment: thank you Nick and Mick for your replay, in the area that I want to transmit information, there is no GSM and Wifi coverage, for the frequency there is no problem I have a licenced frequency (400 MHZ). and yes i need to transmit real time data. thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue but possibly a little more complex. I needed to cover a maximum distance of 22 kilometres and I wanted to monitor over 100 resources ranging from breeding stock to fences and gates etc. I too had no GSM access plus no direct line of sight access as the area is hilly and the breeders like the deep valleys.  The solution I used was to make my own radio network using cheap radio repeaters. Everything was battery operated and was driven by the receivers powering up the transmitters. This means that the units consume only 40 micro amps on standby and when the transmitters transmit, in my case they consume around 100 to 200 milliamps.

In the house I have a little program that transmits a poll to the receivers every so often and waits for the units to reply. This gives me a big advantage because I can, via the repeater trail (as each repeater, the signal goes through, adds its code to the returning message) actually determine were my stock are.

Now for the big issue, how long do the batteries last? Well each unit has a 18650 battery. For the fence and gate controls this is charged by a small 5 volt solar panel and after 2 years running time I have not changed any of them. For the cattle units the length of time between charges depends solely on how often you poll the units (note each unit has its own code) with one exception (a bull who wants to roam and is a real escape artist) I only poll them once or twice a day and I swap the battery every two weeks.

The frequency I use is 433Mhz and the radio transmitters and receivers are very cheap ( less then 10 cents a pair if you by them in Australia) with a very small Attiny (I think) arduino per unit (around 30 cents each) and a length on wire (34.6cm long as an aerial) for the cattle and 69.2cm for the repeaters. Note these calculations are based on the frequency used i.e. 433Mhz.

As I had to install lots of the repeaters I contacted an organisation in China (sorry they no longer exist) and they created a tiny waterproof and rugged capsule that contained everything, while also improving on the design (range wise while reducing power) at a cost of $220 for 100 units not including batterys. I bought one lot as a test and now between myself and my neighbours we bought another 2000 units for only $2750.

In my case this was paid for in less then three months when during calving season I knew exactly were they were calving and was on site to assist. The first time I used it we saved a mother who was having a real issue.

To end this long message I am not an expert but I had an idea and hired people who were and the repeater approach certainly works over long distances and large areas (42 square kilometres).

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the comments above, I'm not sure where you are located but spectrum around the 400mhz range is licensed in many countries so it would be worth checking exactly what you can use.

If this is your target then this is UHF rather than VHF so if you search for 'Raspberry PI UHF shield' or 'Raspberry PI UHF module' you will find some examples of cheap hardware you can add to your raspberry pi to support communication over these frequencies. Most of the results should include some software examples also.

There are also articles on using the pins on the PI to transmit directly by modulating the voltage them - this is almost certainly going to interfere with other communications so I doubt it would meet your needs.

Comment: I tried Googling *"Raspberry Pi UHF module"* and got a bunch of RFID tag readers and 2 Radiometrix modules with a 500m range.... could you maybe name, or link to, a couple of modules you'd recommend for 13 mile range please?

Comment: It is going to depend where you live - UHF is line of site mostly and does not handle hills well. Where I live, a tractor would be lucky to have 13 meters line of sight without a hill, never mind 13 miles. Even on the flat you hit the horizon if you are at standing height at that distance. You may want to look at licensed long distance solutions - probably not in the budget you were hoping for. Radio distances are affected by many different factors, the radio itself, ariel, geography etc so I think it might be good to check the theory a little first before selecting a radio if you can.

Comment: for the liceced frequency, im in training in a company that use already this frequence (400 Mhz) for radio communication using talkie wlakie so i thought if they are using it in sending voice i will use it to send data. so if there is a lot of probleme in radio communication. is it possible to send data over satellite  with raspberry pi. or is there any module support that ?